# Is it mandatory to create local Linux user for Samba share user?

Tags: samba

I have a Samba server with user-level security(`security = user`) security settings and `tdbsam` user credentials back-end. I have allowed only `test-user` to access the Samba share. Is it mandatory to add this `test-user` to `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files? If yes, then why? One reason seems to be that if I add the password to this `test-user` for Samba with `smbpasswd -a test-user`, then some fields like `Full Name`, seen in the output of `pdbedit -L -v`, are missing if entries in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files are missing.

Comment: Does network-based authentication count? Nis, ldap, etc.

Comment: You need a UNIX user because Samba permissions are implemented as UNIX permissions.  For the same reason, in some configurations you'll also need UNIX users for each machine in the domain.  That said however, these UNIX users don't _have_ to live in `passwd` / `shadow`.  As @JeffSchaller points out, they can be in LDAP, NIS, etc.  The point is, the system has to "see" them as UNIX users.  Full name and so on have nothing to do with all that, IIRC they're still read from the TDB database (or whatever Samba uses as a backend).

Comment: @JeffSchaller I guess yes. However, I'm not using network-based authentication. @SatoKatsura In summary, does this mean that in order to access a resource(for example a file) on Samba share one needs both the Linux permissions(and those are associated with user/group) and also Samba permissions stated in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file? For example `writable = no`.

Comment: Yes and no.  If you export a directory as a Samba share, the permissions for files inside are managed by Samba and you aren't supposed to mess with them under its feet.